# Python: Read/write large number of small files

Tags: python, io

I have a large number (about 60K) of small files (<10kb) that I need to process, create a processed version for each file and after that upload the processed files to a ftp server, in less than 1 minute.
I'm using Python 3 with standard read/write function and the performance is really bad.
Do you know if Python have any library support this case ?
Or what can I do to get better performance ?
Thank you so much!

Comment: Post your code. What do you mean by *the performance is really bad*?

Comment: you trying to write to 60k files and upload under a minute? don't think it can be that fast(not including upload speed), i don't understand what do you mean by bad performance, it's the speed ?

Comment: What is being done in your processing? Im sceptical of you being able to open, close, and upload that many files that fast without any processing, but without knowing what you're doing in your processing we can't help you determine where the real (and solvable) performance issue is.

Comment: Thanks for comments. I need to process these files every minute so I need my processing time less than 1 minute to make sure current processing finish before the new processing begin. What I mean by bad performance is that the processing time take more longer and make my system hanged. I just do simple thing in my processing, like remove empty line

Answer (score 0):

remember that I/O operations are **heavy**, and writing or reading files have overhead.

Writing 1024 new files each one is 1kb would take much longer than writing a single new file of 1mb.
Every file you open the system need's to find a place for it on your file system and write it's metadata.

So no matter what you are planning, your performance probably won't be *great*, but I do suggest you to make sure you are doing the best to have the minimum of operations (i.e. upload all the files to the FTP server, instead of open the connection for each file and upload it by itself).
I suggest you to post a snippet from your code so people could help you make sure the code is the most minimal it can be

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I also aware of this. I just wonder if we have better way to read/write file because currently I use "with open file .. as f" , "f.read", "f.write" and the result is not good.

Comment: please post a snippet of your code so we can understand it better, as I said in my comment- the I/O operations are heavy, but you might cut some time from another part of your code which may be not the most efficient

Comment: Thank you @kaki gadol, but my processing part is just simple with 1 line of code like:    if not line.strip(): output.append(line)    so I don't think we can optimize it

Comment: I'm not talking about this part.. Other parts of this code are related to your problem, for example the part where you open each file and save each file.
I'm not sure right now (we can check this), but maybe not going over every line would be faster